# Calculating Absolute Value in Z3

Tags: z3

I have 3 variables `a`, `b` and `c`. I need to calculate `c = absolute(b-a)`.

I encode this statement in Z3 as

```
(assert (>= c 0))
(assert (or (= c (- a b) (= c (- b a))))
```

I was thinking, is there a more efficient way of writing it in Z3?
Does Z3 have internal support for calculating absolute value?
Also, I hope there won't be any performance penalty for writing code like this, rather than using some other way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your encoding is correct. However, users usually encode the absolute value function using

```
(define-fun absolute ((x Int)) Int
  (ite (>= x 0) x (- x)))
```

Then, they can write constraints such as:

```
(assert (= c (absolute (- a b))))
```

Here is the complete example (also available [online at rise4fun](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/9QIf)):

```
(define-fun absolute ((x Int)) Int
  (ite (>= x 0) x (- x)))

(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-const c Int)

(assert (= a 3))
(assert (= b 4))

(assert (= c (absolute (- a b))))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Comment: It is hard to say what is the best encoding. This usually depends on the problem where the absolute value is being used. Your original encoding has one advantage. It explicitly asserts that `c >= 0`. This is not "explict" in the `ite` encoding. Z3 will have to "learn" that if this is relevant for showing that a problem is unsat.

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura: One could simply assert after the definition of `absolute` that all `absolute x` for all `x` is greater than or equal to zero; that should give it equivalent advantage, yes?

Comment: `absolute` defined using `define-fun` is essentially a Macro. If we assert `(forall ((x Int)) (>= (absolute x) 0))`, Z3 will replace `(absolute x)` with `(ite (>= x 0) x (- x))`. So, the quantifier will be just stating a redundant fact. I mean, it cannot be used to help Z3 handling the ground applications of `absolute` in the actual problem.